# absolute position of image

Tags: javascript, html, css

This JS code tries to position an image element `sigImg` by setting its top and left properties to values obtained from a `td` element's `getBoundingClientRect()` so that the image covers the `td.signLabel` element, but the pages shows the image too far to the left and too far to to bottom of the `td` element.

Any idea why and how to make the image covers the `td` element? Thanks

```
let w = window.open();
let doc = w.document;
doc.write(html);
doc.close();

let sigImg = new Image();
sigImg.src = signature;
sigImg.id = 'sign';
sigImg.style.position = 'absolute';

let bounds = doc.querySelector('td.signLabel').getBoundingClientRect();
let top = bounds.top;
let left = bouds.left;

sigImg.style.top = top + 'px';
sigImg.style.left = left + 'px';
sigImg.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; //for illustration
doc.body.appendChild(sigImg);
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>User sign:</td>
    <td class="signLabel">Here:------------------</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: why not just put the image in the cell?

Comment: @epascarello Because its size will miss up the other cell's css for this page which was not authored locally. thus lessen interference with the original layout.

Comment: not when you remove it from the flow

Comment: @epascarello Could you show that in code please? thx

Comment: `position:absolute` removes it from the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image in the cell, set it to absolute.

```css
td img {
position: absolute;
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>This is cell</td>
      <td>This is cell</td>
      <td>This is cell</td>
    </tr>      
    <tr>
      <td>This is cell</td>
      <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" /> This is image
</td>
      <td>This is cell</td>
    </tr>      
    <tr>
      <td>This is cell</td>
      <td>This is cell</td>
      <td>This is cell</td>
    </tr>      
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: One problem, how can I put the image so that it is vertically centered  with the `td`, the other problem is that since the page is not authored locally thus no css file available.

Comment: `margin-top: .5em;` ? All depends on the CSS on the page.

Comment: Since the page is not authored locally, I have to do much work to study and alter its css. not only to center the image but also to include the css you posted along with the page DOM which was downloaded from the web.

Comment: Could you please give the answer in JS only, working with the `html` example I provided, i.e. please put the creation of the css and the td in your solution in javascript. thx